# Reading an image for selected item in the dropdown list from SQL Server database in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to retrieve the image for any selected item from the dropdown list. I am getting an error on the line

```
Image1.ImageUrl = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

Here is my code:

```
  Public Sub Presdorpic()
    myconnection = New SqlConnection(a)
    myconnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT Picture FROM candidates WHERE Fname = '" & ddlPresident.SelectedItem.Text & "'"
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myconnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        Try

            Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("Picture"), Byte())
            Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(data)
            Image1.ImageUrl = Image.FromStream(ms)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: what's the value of `ms` when the error occurs? also, could you provide some of the values of `ddlPresident`?